# How to delete files in mediastore in API 29+?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I'm building gallery app and I have tried to delete a image in mediastore by using `contentResolver().delete()`. but it throws an exception.
How can I resolve it? I'm using API 29.

My code:

```java
public static void removeFile(Context context, String uriStr) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);
    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

Error log:

```
2020-11-09 08:17:54.806 12098-12098/com.example.mygallery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mygallery, PID: 12098
    android.app.RecoverableSecurityException: com.example.mygallery has no access to content://media/external/images/media/39
        at android.app.RecoverableSecurityException$1.createFromParcel(RecoverableSecurityException.java:197)
        at android.app.RecoverableSecurityException$1.createFromParcel(RecoverableSecurityException.java:194)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3281)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2368)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:624)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:2289)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:2255)
        at com.example.mygallery.database.FileHelper.removeFile(FileHelper.java:72)
        at com.example.mygallery.database.ImageDAOImpl.deleteMediaFile(ImageDAOImpl.java:83)
        at com.example.mygallery.fragment.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:165)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You can no longer silently delete a file ouside the app's scope. see https://www.mdeditor.tw/pl/pZ1a. The user needs to be asked to confirm the deletion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's all that I need..